# Generate SPARQL query for DBpedia giving distinct result

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using SPARQL for querying the DBpedia database. My first query was the following:

```
select ?s1 ( bif:search_excerpt ( bif:vector ( 'TENDULKAR', 'SACHIN' ) , ?o1 ) ) where 
{ 
 { 
  { 
    select ?s1, ( ?sc * 3e-1 ) as ?sc, ?o1, ( sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) as ?          rank, ?g where 
    { 
      quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap 
      { 
        graph ?g 
        { 
          ?s1 ?s1textp ?o1 .
          ?o1 bif:contains ' ( TENDULKAR AND SACHIN ) ' option ( score ?sc ) .

        }
       }
     }
   order by desc ( ?sc * 3e-1 + sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?s1 ) ) ) limit 20 offset 0 
  }
 }
}
```

Now even if I apply the `DISTINCT` keyword to the query it gives the same result as before.

I want distinct results from this query.

Comment: Could you add the (partial) result of your query and perhaps a short description of what data you're trying to get? That may help give answers. Are you seeing exactly duplicate results?

Comment: ![]output of my query[1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kaUtd.jpg


now here when i queried sachin tendulkar in dbpedia then i got desired output which is shown in figure..i just want to filter out repeted output

Comment: Well, when I try the adapted query (the current query breaks, because there is space between `?` and `rank`) on DBpedia, I get a second column with the HTML for the descriptions in your image. When I add `DISTINCT` to the outer query, there are no duplicates anymore: every result (row) has a different combination of values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sparql Keys vs distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419800/sparql-keys-vs-distinct-values)