# DISTINCT only on one value with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I want to retrieve with SPARQL the list of the italian cities with more than 100k  of population and I'm using the following query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?city ?name ?pop WHERE { 
    ?city a dbo:Settlement .
    ?city foaf:name ?name .
    ?city dbo:populationTotal ?pop .
    ?city dbo:country ?country .
    ?city dbo:country dbpedia:Italy .
  FILTER (?pop > 100000) 
}
```

In the results I get for example in two different lines (which represent the same entity, but with different names):

> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bologna   "Bologna"@en    384038
>
> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bologna   "Comune di Bologna"@en  384038

How can I use `SELECT DISTINCT` only in the column `?city` but still having as output the outher columns?

Comment: Possibly related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419800/sparql-keys-vs-distinct-values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group by a specific column and then use the `SAMPLE()` aggregate to select one of the values from the other columns e.g.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?city (SAMPLE(?name) AS ?cityName) (SAMPLE(?pop) AS ?cityPop)
WHERE
{ 
    ?city a dbo:Settlement .
    ?city foaf:name ?name .
    ?city dbo:populationTotal ?pop .
    ?city dbo:country ?country .
    ?city dbo:country dbpedia:Italy .
    FILTER (?pop > 100000) 
}
GROUP BY ?city
```

So by grouping on the `?city` you get only a single row per city, since you have grouped by `?city` you can't directly select variables that aren't group variables.

You must instead use the `SAMPLE()` aggregate to pick one of the values for each of the non-group variables you wish to have in the final results.  This will select one of the values of `?name` and `?pop` to return as `?cityName` and `?cityPop` respectively